# How to make the save function in Parse work in synchronous manner

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, parse-platform

my Initial code:

```
var Group = Parse.Object.extend("Group");
var myGroup = new Group();
myGroup.set("groupName", "book");
myGroup.set("category", "Hobby");
myGroup.save(null, {
    success: function(object) {
    },
    error: function(error) {
        // Fail
    }
});
alert("now go");
```

So output:
First now go is printed and then save function worked due to asynchronous nature

Then i modified as:

```
var Group = Parse.Object.extend("Group");
var myGroup = new Group();
myGroup.set("groupName", "book");
myGroup.set("category", "Hobby");
myGroup.save(null).then(
    function(object) {
    },
    function(error) {
        // Fail
    }
);
alert("now go");
```

Now output: **TypeError: myGroup.save(...).then is not a function** but the group object gets added in the Parse I don't know why? Why i am getting this error?

So, i have searched on stackoverflow and google, bu can't find useful to me. I am new to this asuychronous stuff, really. What i wanted to make this save function work as synchronous, I have read Promise stuff but can't really get it.

Comment: Please anybody please help me!!! I am really waiting for an answer... I know this may be simple stuff for many people, but I am new and that "TypeError: myGroup.save(...).then is not a function" is really irritating me.

Comment: Finally I got the answer why this second error was there... The answer is: the version issue, I was using 1.1.14 before and when I used 1.3.3 It worked without error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promises don't let you turn asynchronous code into synchronous code. They're an alternative way of structuring your asynchronous code – one that's often easier to understand with complex chains. But the two code samples you posted are effectively equivalent.

There's rarely any reason to make your JavaScript asynchronous, especially when posting updates to a server. JavaScript is (generally) single-threaded, which means that it can only do one thing at a time. On many devices, if your JavaScript waited for your `save` call to complete before continuing, then the entire interface would lock up. Even if the user could scroll around, they wouldn't be able to interact with any other elements in your application. There's got to be a better way.

That better way is using **callback functions** to do something once the `save` call has completed. For instance, if you wanted your `alert` call to happen after you've successfully saved, here's one way to do it:

```
myGroup.save(null, {
    success: function(object) {
        alert("now go");
    }
});
```

More practically, let's say you've got a couple of ([jQuery-dependent](http://jquery.com/)) functions in your app that let you show and hide a status bar:

```
<!-- Somewhere in your HTML templates... -->
<div class="status-loading" style="display: none">
    <img src="spinner.gif" alt="Spinner" />
    <p>Loading...</p>
</div>
```

```
/* Somewhere in your JavaScript... */
function showStatus() { 
     $('.status-loading').show();
}

function hideStatus() { 
     $('.status-loading').hide();
}
```

You can now use these methods when you save your item. First, show the status message; then try to save the item; and when it succeeds, hide it. Thus:

```
showStatus();
myGroup.save(null, {
    success: function(object) {
        hideStatus();
    }
});
```

---

For bonus points, in this case you don't even need that **anonymous function** within your save call. Because the only thing it's doing is calling `hideStatus`, you could tell `save` to call `hideStatus` directly on success:

```
myGroup.save(null, {success: hideStatus});
```

---

Finally, the error message you're getting - `.then` is not a function - means that the `.save` method is returning something that isn't a Promise. [Parse promises have a `.then` function](http://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Promise.html), but whatever is being returned doesn't have that function. I'm not sure, but [the Parse documentation for `.save`](http://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Object.html#save) doesn't list a one-argument way to call it. So you could try this instead, to pass in empty options:

```
myGroup.save(null, {}).then(
    function() { alert("Successful"); }, 
    function() { alert("Failed"); }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation but I am still getting the error message.

Comment: What about if you go back to using the version without promises - like your first code sample - and move your alert inside your success callback?

Comment: Finally I got the answer why this second error was there... The answer is: the version issue, I was using 1.1.14 before and when I used 1.3.3 It worked without error.